# Android realm findAllAsync() freezing UI

Tags: android, realm

when I'm querying lot of elements the UI get freeze.

```
realm.where(TVRealm.class).equalTo("favorite", true).findAllAsync()
                .addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<TVRealm>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChange(RealmResults<TVRealm> element) {
                        List<TV> tvList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (TVRealm tvRealm : element) {
                            tvList.add(prepareTV(TVRealm.toTV(tvRealm), true));
                        }
                        listener.onDataChange(tvList);
                    }
                });
```

I thought that findAllAsync() will run on other thread and avoid the issue but not. 
Does anyone knows how to avoid this issue? Maybe there is another way without using findAllAsync() method.

Thanks.

Comment: what realm version are you using?

Comment: Your UI freezes because your mapping logic happens on the UI thread, and evaluated for every single element - not because Realm is slow. Realm wasn't designed to have every single element read in a loop; that's why by default, `RealmResults` is just a lazy-loaded "cursor" that gives you lazy-loaded proxies

Comment: so the solution is to revise your code in such a way that `tvList.add(prepareTV(TVRealm.toTV(tvRealm), true));` won't be there, and just use `TVRealm` directly

Answer (score 2):

According to official `Realm` document, `findAllAsync` works in a background thread.
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-queries

I think your data changes too often and so you're trying to notify ui too often. So you're blocking ui. I guess you are notifying a `RecyclerView` adapter in your `onDataChange` method.

Also if your result list has too many items, every time when your data changed exploring the results and adding items to a new list may block ui.

Comment: The data is not changing often it's happening when I create the fragment. I have a drawer layout when I select a drawer option I change fragment. When the drawer start closing the app freezes for a moment then the fragment is loaded correctly.

Comment: while opening / closing drawer inflating a fragment and replace it can block ui for a moment. one of the simplest way to avoid it, you can just wait drawer to close and after it's closed you can replace your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't make mistake, while RealmResults is updating, for each change you create new collection with new models and update UI. Try to call `findAll()` in another thread, map results to TVs and post completed list of TVs to UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

why dont you try this

```
RealmResult<item> res=realm.where(item.class).where("name","sanjay").findAll();
```

it will get all the data at a time.